# C++ circular dependency returning by value?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

When returning by pointer or reference in C++, it is easy to break circular dependencies with forward declarations. But with do you do in a case where you have to return by value?

Consider the simplified example below

```
struct Foo {
  Bar bar() {return Bar{*this}; }
};

struct Bar {
  Foo foo;
}
```

Is there any way to break the circular dependency? Trying to forward declare Bar just leads to a complaint about an incomplete return type.

Comment: Don't define the function inline. `struct Bar; struct Foo {Bar bar();}; struct Bar {Foo foo;}; Bar Foo::Bar() {return Bar{*this};}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define the two types, declaring their member functions. Then define the member functions outside the class, and even after the second class definition.

```
struct Bar;
struct Foo {
  Bar bar();
};

struct Bar {
  Foo foo;
};

Bar Foo::bar() {return Bar{*this}; }
```

Comment: Well now I feel silly. I got confused by the error message and thought the problem was with the return type, not the inline definition.

Comment: It's really the return _statement_ which needs the copy ctor.